# Which Database would be the best option to use?

Tags: android, mongodb, cassandra

Actually I'm designing a social media app using mongodb and it's almost ready to release . But today I was checking some posts about Cassandra vs MongoDB and in those posts it was mentioned that for heavy writes Cassandra should be used instead of MongoDB.

So I'm confused should I migrate to Cassandra from MongoDB or should I release my app in MongoDB itself.

Please do suggest what would be the best db for my case. I have messaging, picture uploading, video uploading (in future) in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While both are NoSQL databases, they are very different. Looking at a few key characteristics you can determine which one is better for your application (although I will say that if your application is so close to release, does it make sense to delay in order to redesign the database portion? Just asking.)

- Objects: do you need flexibility in your data model? Mongo uses an
  expressive object model that includes indexing the property of an
  object. Cassandra uses a more traditional table structure with rows
  and columns of a specific data type.
- Secondary Indexes: do you need secondary indexes and a more flexible
  query model? MongoDB has full support of secondary indexes. Cassandra
  has cursory support for secondary indexes, queries are more
  traditional.
- High Availability: Do you need 100% uptime? With MongoDB's single
  master model you will have downtime if the master is down and while
  the slaves elect a new master. Cassandra supports multiple masters
  and can achieve 100% uptime for writes.
- Query Language support: do you need query language support? MongoDB
  has no support for a query language, whereas Cassandra supports CQL
  that is very similar to SQL.
- High Write Throughput: if you have a large number of concurrent
  writes happening, then Cassandra has the high write throughput
  advantage.